# When any tabs are refreshed, the page is automatically navigating to first tab

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

in the below app, whenever the user is neither in tab2 or tab3 and clicks on refresh, the page is taking to tab1. Can we avoid this and make sure the page is staying in the respective tab post refreshing :slight_smile: Is it possible to achieve please guide me.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id="inTabset",
    tabPanel("Tab 1",actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the third tab")
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
    tabPanel("Tab 3", "there!"))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$switch_tab, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",selected = "Tab 3")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep state and Shiny has [a bookmark system](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) for this but in your case you will probably wish to have a more invisible mechanism.

Add the [Cookie.js JavaScript library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to your Shiny app like this:

```
 tags$head(tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js")),
        tags$head(tags$script(src="app.js")),
        tabsetPanel(
            id="inTabset",
            tabPanel("Tab 1",actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the third tab")),
            tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
            tabPanel("Tab 3", "there!")),
```

and create an `app.js` file in the [www-directory](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html) of your Shiny root with the following content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[data-toggle='tab']").click(function(){
     const tabId = $(this).data("value");
     Cookies.set('tabId', tabId);
   })
   const cookieTabId = Cookies.get("tabId");
   if(cookieTabId){
     console.log(`Restoring tab '${cookieTabId}'`); 
     $(`a[data-value='${cookieTabId}']`).tab('show');
   }
 })
```

The most difficult part in the above JS are the jQuery selectors and the `show()` method [from Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp).

You can also transfer the selected tab value to the server and save the session values for each and every user in a data store. It would create state persistence beyond the user's browser.

[The solution can be downloaded from here.](https://orbifold.net/temp/statefulShiny.zip)

Comment: Thanks. Want to check with you. Is there no other option other than creating app.js file. I thought it might be just a single line of code I am not an expert in this. But want to check with you

Comment: You can add the JS code inline as well but there are some annoying issues with special characters (like '>' and quotes) if you do so.

Comment: I tried creating app.js and with the code. The tabs are still going to first tab :)